# Activate a Button in java with the enter key

Tags: java, swing, button, awt, jbutton

This is the code I'm using.
I'm working towards a peer to peer "IM" and
I want to know how to activate my send message button with the enter key. I also want to know how I might go about making two of these work together and chat over the internet. If I need a server in the middle I have one. Peer to peer is the best option though, maybe hamatchi. Heck, If you can help two instances of the program on the same computer work together that would be very beneficial. I will make two different programs if I need to.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;


public class The_Emissary extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                The_Emissary frame = new The_Emissary();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public The_Emissary() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    //Panels

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setToolTipText("Messages will pop up here");
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    panel.add(textArea);
    //Buttons And Text Boxes
    final TextField textField = new TextField();
    panel_1.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    Button SendMSG = new Button("Send Message");
    panel_1.add(SendMSG, BorderLayout.EAST);


    SendMSG.addActionListener(this);

    SendMSG.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int A = 0; 

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try {
                    textArea.getDocument().insertString(0, "On " + new Date() + " Anon said: " + textField.getText(), null);
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                A++;
                System.out.println(A);

            }});      
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: SO is not a 'one stop fix my code shop.  Limit it to one question per question and take up the P2P aspect on another question.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use the same `ActionListener` you've used for your button with your text field.

```
final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
panel_1.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);


JButton SendMSG = new JButton("Send Message");
panel_1.add(SendMSG, BorderLayout.EAST);

ActionListener sendListener = new ActionListener() {
    int A = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textArea.setText("On " + new Date() + " Anon said: " + textField.getText() + "\n" + textArea.getText());
        A++;
        System.out.println(A);
    }
};
SendMSG.addActionListener(sendListener);
textField.addActionListener(sendListener);
```

This provides a platform independent solution, because it allows the text field to decide what is actually a "accept" action for that platform.

**Code Review**

You're mixing heavy/AWT weight components with light/Swing components, this is never going to end well.

Stick to the Swing framework, it's more flexible and more widely used and supported

- Use `JTextField` instead of `TextField`

Comment: @RexPRGMER : Or you can set the said `JButton` in question, to be the default Button, by using `frameObject.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonObject)`, as cited in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9314931/1057230) :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw The only reason I wouldn't use that approach is that the text field is likely to consume the enter key, therefore not allowing the `JRootPane` the opportunity to trigger the default button ... Happens to me all the time with login dialogs :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Ahha, that's a new insight. I didn't knew about this consuming behaviour for `JTextField`. Thanks for sharing this knowledge :-) Though I just realized, that this thingy I mentioned works only on Windows, I guess, if I am not mistaken, so another limitation of the approach `(setting a JButton as default Button)` as mentioned by me :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw I'm surprised to hear it own works on Windows...I'll need to try it next time I have some spare time on my Mac - Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MadProgrammer : A quick search on the Tutorials gave me - `The exact implementation of the default button feature depends on the look and feel. For example, in the Windows look and feel, the default button changes to whichever button has the focus, so that pressing Enter clicks the focused button. When no button has the focus, the button you originally specified as the default button becomes the default button again.` So I guess my comment needs to be corrected, as it behaves differently on Windows, not how I thought it use to :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw FYI - This is actually the first idea I had too ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback, I need all the help I can get being thirteen and all

Comment: I was coding (all be it basic) from 8. I have to admit, jumping to OO was huge learning curve, I can't imagine what it would be like starting of with. Also, we only had 2 colours and text :)